# Verifying the size of a subdirectory

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, scripting

I want to write a python script that aims to traverse a root directory `E:\abc` and find whether a subdirectory `Test` is available in any directories or not. If `Test` is available and **not empty**, print `OK` if `Test` directory is empty, otherwise print `NOT_OK`. Please help.

Comment: Did you try to write some code for this? Can you include it in the question? (more generally, it seems that you can solve this using 'find' - no need for a python script.)

Comment: I had to use python. For now I have written only below given code as I am a beginner in python  and have not that much idea about python

Comment: Please add the question, and include the code you've written.

Answer (score 0):

```
  # determine size of a given folder in MBytes
import os
from pathlib import Path
# pick a folder you have ...
folder = Path(r'E:\abc')
folder_size = 0
files = folder.rglob('*')
for (path, dirs, files) in os.walk(folder):
  for file in files:
    filename = os.path.join(path, file)
    folder_size += os.path.getsize(filename)
print("Folder = %0.1f MB" % (folder_size/(1024*1024.0)))

if folder_size > 1:
    print("ok")
else:
    print("Not_ok")
```